# SDK for sony ILCE QX1L

Tags: sony, sony-camera-api

Is it possible to attach this camera to computer through cable and get SDK so that it would be possible to control it through our own made software?

We need for automated photobooth.

If not, which camera should be used? (from cheapest with interchangeable lenses)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately all of the Sony cameras that support the Camera Remote API will only work connected to the camera over wifi.